# Exploit regex_search

Tags: regex, boost

I am trying to use Boost regular expressions module to extract the numbers from character strings of this format: "{  12354,21354, 123 }"

The following code has been written to this end. As I do this operation in a loop the string is stored in `it->c_str()`:

```
boost::cmatch matches;
boost::regex reNumber("-*[0-9.]+");
boost::regex reFiniteValues(" *\\{.*\\} *");
std::cout << "\ttesting for finite values" << std::endl;
if (boost::regex_match(it->c_str(), matches, reFiniteValues))
{
    boost::regex_search(it->c_str(), matches, reNumber);
    std::cout << "matches.size(): " << matches.size() << std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << matches[i] << std::endl;
    }
    if (matches.size() > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\tpattern found" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }
}
```

However the size of the `matches` object is 1, and it only contains 12354 in this example. I would like to know how I can retrieve all the numbers from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try to loop regex_search().   -

```
typedef std::string::const_iterator SITR;

std::string str = it->c_str();
SITR start = str.begin();
SITR end   = str.end();
boost::smatch m;

while ( boost::regex_search (start, end, m, reNumber ) )
{
    std::cout << m[0].str() << std::endl;
    start = m[0].second;
}
```